# If statement acting like while statement python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

For some reason, this code:

```
    def display_jan_appointments():  
        for item in appointment_dates:  
            if item[0:2] == "01" and item[3:5] == "01" and not adding:
                pygame.draw.ellipse(screen, BLUE, [915, 275, 20, 20])
                jan_1_index.append(appointment_dates.index(item))
                jan1 = True
                global jan1
```

Infinitely adds the index of the item to the jan_1_index list. I'm not sure why, as the if statement should only be iterated through once, because it's not a while statement. Is it do with the code being in a function, or is it something else?

Edit: When I print the list out, it outputs:

```
    [0]
    [0, 0]
    [0, 0, 0]
    [0, 0, 0, 0]
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

and so on.

Double edit: I produced a small section of code with everything necessary.

```
appointment_dates = ["01/01", "01/01"]
jan_1_index = []
adding = False
for item in appointment_dates:
    if item[0:2] == "01" and item[3:5] == "01" and not adding:
        jan_1_index.append(appointment_dates.index(item))               
        print(jan_1_index)
```

This code, however, outputs the list like it is supposed to, just [0, 0]. Why is this?

Comment: Can you check that jan_1_index points not to the same object as appointment_dates?

Comment: @DAXaholic They're two separate arrays.

Comment: How have you determined that it's adding "infinitely"? If the program locks up, how do you know that particular list is becoming infinitely big? No, if statements don't suddenly become infinite loops because they're inside functions, that would be unusable...

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler The program doesn't lock up, and I've got the list being printed out which, every line printed out, it increases by one.

Comment: If it's not locking up, then the if statement cannot be acting like a while statement, right? Otherwise it would never leave there, and would lock up... can you post more code? Are you calling display_jan_appointments too many times?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler It's not quite acting like a while statement in that it locks up, it just adds to the array infinitely while the item's characters are what I specified.

Comment: Double check the result of `appointment_dates is jan_1_index` and that `and not adding` looks a little sus. as if it's possibly supposed to be being changed at some point but it's not possible to tell as to where given your current code... There's not enough to be going on here - can you look at producing a [mcve]?

Comment: @JonClements Essentially, what I'm making is a calendar and this part of the program is detecting if the appointments are for Jan 1st. The not adding part is just making sure that the circle indicating that an appointment is on this day is not blitted when the user is adding an appointment.

Comment: @Kronyklos Thanks for that info. but we still need to see more code to identify the problem...

Comment: @Kronyklos at the moment - my best guess of what could be tripping you up (assuming the program isn't running infinitely) is that `list.index` will only return the index of the **first** occurrence of item... So you'll always get back 0 if that's the first match...

Comment: @JonClements I only just noticed that, thanks! Do you have any idea why it would be appending infinitely, though?

Comment: @Kronyklos as mentioned - something could be mutating `appointment_dates` - what happens if you do: `jan_1_index = [idx for idx, item in enumerate(appointment_dates) if item[:2] == '01' and item[3:5] == '01']` which is the correct way to do this anyway and will avoid the fact if the two lists have someone happened to be the same...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues with the code - `list.index` will always return the index of the *first* match - so effectively, you'll get repeated indices. The other issue (which is hard to tell from your code) is that likely something is mutating `appointment_dates`...

The Pythonic way to do this is via using a list-comp, eg:

```
jan_1_index = [
    idx for idx, item in enumerate(appointment_dates) 
    if item[:2] == '01' and item[3:5] == '01' # and not adding
]
```